# calling module with def plus variables

Tags: ruby

I'm a bit confused as to making this work. Inside the definition contains a shell command, "shell_cmd". How do I get my variables input correctly into the shell command via calling it with puts or without? What is the correct way to do this?

```
module MOD1

    def MOD1.add_zone_port(zone, port)

    addportzone = `shell_cmd --obj1=#{zone} --obj2=#{port}`
    puts #{addportzone}
    end
end

puts MOD1.add_zone_port("zone", "port")
```

Comment: Do you want to execute the shell command or just make a string?

Comment: Why did you comment out half of the last line in your method?

Comment: thanks for the uncommenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you were in the right track?

You want to put a variable within curly braces if you are trying to have it interpreted within a string for instance...

The below should work:

```
module MOD1
  def MOD1.add_zone_port(zone, port)
    `shell_cmd --obj1=#{zone} --obj2=#{port}`
  end
end

puts MOD1.add_zone_port("zone", "port")
```

Or in case you dont want to bother giving method the modules namespace...

```
module MOD1
  def add_zone_port(zone, port)
    `shell_cmd --obj1=#{zone} --obj2=#{port}`
  end
end
include MOD1
puts MOD1.add_zone_port("zone", "port")
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked is: ruby version 2.0

module MOD1
  def MOD1.add_zone_port(zone, port)
    `shell_cmd --obj1=#{zone} --obj2=#{port}`
  end
end

puts MOD1.add_zone_port(zone, port)